# The following question is based on coordinate geometry and triangles.

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

Show that the line joining the circumcentre and incentre of a triangle will pass through the orthocentre and centroid of the triangle formed by joining the points of contact of the inscribed circle.

I tried a lot but literally have no idea how to start with and how to approach in a simple way. I tried finding coordinates but it is almost impossible. Please help.

Comment: They are all situated on the so-called (common !) Euler line of the triangle and its mid-triangle : http://128.192.17.191/EMAT6680Su12/Graves/FinalPage/Additonal%20Assignment/Eulerlineandmedialtri.html

Comment: @Jean Marie. Thanks sir the article helped me.